# ModelAttribute not mapping application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, spring, modelattribute

I have a somewhat simplistic controller configured as thus:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/savearticle", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Object saveArticle(@ModelAttribute("article")RawArticle rawArticle);
```

Using snippets of code taken from [here](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/unit-testing-of-spring-mvc-controllers-configuration/), I made a test case for the controller that looks like this:

```
MvcResult resultActions =
         mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/user/savearticle")
         .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
         .content(convertObjectToForumUrlEncodedBytes(rawArticle)))
         .andReturn();
```

and I simply print out the result. In any case, the ModelAttribute "rawArticle" keeps ending up as null when it enters the controller's implementation, however when I use this:

```
MvcResult resultActions = mockMvc.perform(
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/user/savearticle")
        .param("title", rawArticle.getTitle())
        .param("tags", rawArticle.getTags())
        .param("body", rawArticle.getBody())
        .param("author", rawArticle.getAuthor())).andReturn();
```

the mapping actually works like a charm. What I want though is that the first test be processed correctly as it seems so wrong that it's not being mapped as I thought it should be, similarly the controller is primarily being used by another program over the network using apache http (which somehow automatically passes a urlencoded form).

Do you guys have any idea where I could've made an error? I wouldn't mind posting snippets of my context configuration if you think you need it to evaluate the problem (or my pom for that matter, but just telling me what libraries I may have missed should be enough)

Update:
I made a mistake of inserting the POJO into a session in test number 1, I simply removed it here. The question stands the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content is the content body of the request, you are using a content type which expects everything encoded in the URL **not** in the content body. Spring does data binding based on the request parameters if you want to use the content body you have to use `@RequestBody` instead of `@ModelAttribute`.